# Issue Migrating Parse.com Images to S3 Bucket

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform, amazon-s3

Ok, so I have a Parse.com app I've been working on way too long trying to get migrated.  My original Parse class had some file images in it, and I tried using the parse-files-utils tool to move them all over to S3.  I did this, but something went wrong in the process and it renamed all the image files on Parse, while not actually moving them to S3.  So, I deleted all the images (this is after the mongoDB has already been set up) and re-uploaded files, this time they had different image names.  I then set everything up and run the parse-files-utils to upload to S3 and I get this:

```
Initializing transfer configuration...
Connecting to MongoDB
Successfully connected to MongoDB
Initializing s3 adapter
Fetching schema...
Fetching all objects with files...
Processing 41 files
Saving files with s3
Failed request (403) skipping: https://fritchdirectory.s3.amazonaws.com/tfss-1ae62b0d-d71c-415a-838a-51f4fc515085-chisum.jpg
Failed request (403) skipping: https://fritchdirectory.s3.amazonaws.com/tfss-c06d5233-9037-4c21-8909-0006f5493b6b-buchanan.JPG
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?  When I go to the Parse site itself and check on one of those images to download, the filename matches EXACTLY.

Answer (score 1):

If you're migrating from Parse.com, make sure to use
    serverURL: " https://api.parse.com/1",
I had this issue because I accidentally put in my new URL instead of the one I was migrating from.

Comment: I was using `http://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse` because that's what the guide said to do.  I've already got the main data moved to mongoDB, this was just to move the images to S3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble, I wrote an open source tool that can run on Heroku to easily migrate your S3 files without also changing the data in your database: https://github.com/modernistik/parse-file-migration . It also has a guide that should be easy to follow.

With this solution, you can run against your own parse server (ex. `http://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse`) with the `fileKey` parameter set. Once you set it up, you can run the parse-file-migration app on Heroku, which will copy all the files from Parse.com (for all of your models and classes) over to your designated S3 bucket. Once you are done with the tool, you can remove the use of the `fileKey` in Parse Server after Jan 30th (Parse.com shutdown date) and all the files should be served on your S3 bucket.

Comment: Thank you for that, I will try it out.  I did a bunch of stuff manually that got it "working".  I just manually uploaded each file to my bucket, made sure the filename in mongoDb matched, but then had to add permission to make al image files in the S3 bucket available for everyone to open/download before it would be visible.